# How to fix GetUrl and PDF for google script (see error message)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

Basically I copied my google sheet and I tested out a button for it, but the button didnt work and it kept giving me an error message.

the specific part of my code below that is not working is

`var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);`

it works fine if it is the original copy but if I am to copy it to create more sheets, then it does not work. It keeps saying it cannot get the pdf for some reason.

I added a lot of quotation marks around the spot that the debugger is saying is having issues.

```
function sendSheetToPdfandEMail(){ // this is the function to call
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[5]; // it will send sheet 5 which is the first sheet in the spreadsheet.
  // if you change the number, change it also in the parameters below
  var shName = sh.getName()
  //var shNum = (sheet.getIndex())-1; (could use instead to figure out if the charts have to be shown on a tab or not)
  //sendSpreadsheetToPdf(shNum, shName, ss.getRange('F2').getValue(),"test email with the adress in cell A1 ", "This is it !"); Then this would be what to replace the bottom part to with minor adjustments
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('FS SCORE SHEET');
  sendSpreadsheetToPdf(5, shName, targetSheet.getRange('F2').getValue(),"Graphical Report", "Please See Attached");
}

function sendSpreadsheetToPdf(sheetNumber, pdfName, email,subject, htmlbody) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId()
  var sheetId = sheetNumber ? spreadsheet.getSheets()[sheetNumber].getSheetId() : null;
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' //export as pdf
    + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId))
    // following parameters are optional...
    + '&size=A1' // paper size
    + '&portrait=false' // orientation, false for landscape
    + '&fitw=true' // fit to width, false for actual size
    + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true' //hide optional headers and footers
    + '&gridlines=false' // hide gridlines
    + '&fzr=false'; // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options); // <--- error line
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    var mailOptions = {
      attachments:blob, htmlBody:htmlbody
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      email,
      subject+" (" + pdfName +")",
      "html content only",
      mailOptions
    );
  }
}
```

### error message:

> Request failed for https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19i41c_pl5Y-ofElFnEdaGg7RlyfWc765NWZbvHkZT6Q/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&gid=313300074&size=A1&portrait=false&fitw=true&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true&gridlines=false&fzr=false returned code 401. Truncated server response:   Unauthorized
>
> ## Unauthorized
>
> ### Error 401
>
> (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: I think that your script works. So can I ask you about `if I am to copy it to create more sheets, then it does not work.`? And can I ask you about the difference between the situation, which worked with `the original copy`, and the current situation, which has the issue?

Comment: do you have the same permissions on the 'original' sheet as the ones you're copying to?

Comment: my guess is an issue the token you're passing. the token is tied to you, not the container of the script (as I understand it).

Comment: hmm. @tanaike the situation is the same. The only difference is that the I clicked "make a copy" and the secondary copy is an exact copy of the original. Unsure what the issue is.

Comment: and @danOswalt the permissions are the same. I even removed added in admins priveleges to my second account and that still did not work. How would I set it up so the token is tied to the container of the script?

Comment: @Kush V Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the created date of the original Spreadsheet?

Comment: @tanaike hey the date is july 12th for the original spreadsheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the case that the created date is before April 8, 2019, when the Spreadsheet including the bound script is copied, I experienced that such error occurred. But from your replying, I think that the situation is different from above. In this case, as a workaround, how about using the script for the copied Spreadsheet as a library? I apologize that I cannot propose the method for directly resolving your issue.